# Выбор аргумента из списка при инициализации экземпляра класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Предположим, есть список доступных рас персонажа.

Как при инициализации реализовать выбор из существующего списка, что бы исключить опечатки и прочие связанные с этим трудности?

```
race_list = ['Orc','Elf','Human']
class Hero:
    def __init__(self,race):
        self.race = race
```

У меня есть идея вывести список рас и предложить выбор:

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self,race=int(input('Выберите расу героя:\n1: Orc\n2: Elf\n3: Human\n'))):
        self.race = race_list[race - 1]

Anduin = Hero()
```

Есть ли более элегантный метод реализации?

Comment: А вы уверенны, что это правильный подход? Получается что экземпляр персонажа не будет создан, пока ему аргумент не дадут... как - то не логично. Правильней создать экземпляр с аргументом None и отдельно блок меню для настройки персонажа. Потому что пользователь захочет посмотреть, а как это все выглядит при настройке... Кроме того, если игра консольная - нет проблем. Пользователю будет доступна консоль. Но если игру реализовывать на pygame... как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: может `input` убрать из инициализации? Далее `race` сделать обязательным аргументом и при создании объекта его передавать. Из `inputa` или каким другим способом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Сделал бы базовый класс BaseRace
2. Для каждой рассы создавал бы класс, унаследованный от BaseRace
   *(По хорошему нужна [фабрика классов](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/abstract-factory/python/example))*
3. Рассу бы принимал из input-а или откуда угодно, создавая соответствующий экземпляр класса
4. В вашем классе в init проверял бы через issubclass проверял бы, что расса это один из существующих классов:

```
def __init__(self, race):
assert issubclass(race, BaseRace)
```

Comment: Мне подходит это решение. Благодарю!